# flutter dragable and dragtarget sample

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a scenario of a video chat screen where I need to drag the preview container anywhere in the screen(preferably left,right of the both top and bottom of the screen. By default the container holding the camera will be on the bottom right corner.

My understanding is we need multiple dragtargets in the same screen (stack) and move the draggable widget. I was not able to find a good sample for the same. Any basic sample with a container would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

I think I got this by using InteractiveViewer(
boundaryMargin: EdgeInsets.all(double.infinity),

Instead of dragable and dragtargets